# How to return multiple images with flask

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests, endpoint

I simply create a flask endpoint that returns an image from the file system. I've done some tests with postman and it works fine.
Here's the instruction that does this:

```
return send_file(image_path, mimetype='image/png')
```

Now I try to send back several images at the same time, for example in my case, I try to send back each separately each face that appears in a given image.
Can anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to encode each picture into bytes, append it to a list, then return the result (source : [How to return image stream and text as JSON response from Python Flask API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57346338/how-to-return-image-stream-and-text-as-json-response-from-python-flask-api) ). This is the code:

```
import io
from base64 import encodebytes
from PIL import Image
from flask import jsonify
from Face_extraction import face_extraction_v2

def get_response_image(image_path):
    pil_img = Image.open(image_path, mode='r') # reads the PIL image
    byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
    pil_img.save(byte_arr, format='PNG') # convert the PIL image to byte array
    encoded_img = encodebytes(byte_arr.getvalue()).decode('ascii') # encode as base64
    return encoded_img



@app.route('/get_images',methods=['GET'])
def get_images():

    ##reuslt  contains list of path images
    result = get_images_from_local_storage()
    encoded_imges = []
    for image_path in result:
        encoded_imges.append(get_response_image(image_path))
    return jsonify({'result': encoded_imges})
```

I hope that my solution and also the solution of @Mooncrater help.

Comment: This is much better than my answer. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41374226/5345646), you can zip your images and send them:

> This is **all the code** you need using the [`Zip files`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html). It will
> return a zip file with all of your files.
>
> In my program everything I want to zip is in an `output` folder so i
> just use `os.walk` and put it in the zip file with `write`. Before
> returning the `file` you need to **close** it, if you don't **close**
> it will return an empty file.
>
> ```
> import zipfile
> import os
> from flask import send_file
>
> @app.route('/download_all')
> def download_all():
>     zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Name.zip','w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
>     for root,dirs, files in os.walk('output/'):
>         for file in files:
>             zipf.write('output/'+file)
>     zipf.close()
>     return send_file('Name.zip',
>             mimetype = 'zip',
>             attachment_filename= 'Name.zip',
>             as_attachment = True)
> ```
>
> In the `html` I simply call the route:
>
> ```
> <a href="{{url_for( 'download_all')}}"> DOWNLOAD ALL </a>
> ```
>
> I hope this helped somebody. :)

Comment: thanks for this answer it's a good solution to do this, but here I can't return any other result (json result associated with the image). but it works fine.