# How to send multiple byteIO files from Flask endpoint to Vue using axios and file encoding

Tags: vue.js, flask, axios, byte, blob

### TL;DR

Flask:

**docx** --> **bytesIO** --*encodebytes()*--> **bytes** --*decode()*--> **string** --> **array** containing multiple of those string.

Vue:

**array** containing those strings --**?**--> **blob**

---

### Question

I am trying to return multiple byteIO files from Flask endpoint to my Vue application at once.

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011280/how-to-generate-a-docx-in-python-and-save-it-in-memory), it may be done by converting the byteIO files to string using bytesencode() and .decode().
Then the string is attached to an array and json serialized.

I don't know how it can be done however to reverse the convestion in Vue back to a necessary blob object (which will be downloaded).

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

How I create my bytesIO document files from docx template (my code is heavily inspired by [snakecharmerb's answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011280/how-to-generate-a-docx-in-python-and-save-it-in-memory)):

```
def from_template_multiple(context): # context is a dict containing custom attributes to be rendered in the document

    template = DocxTemplate(template_document.docx')

    # Create in-memory buffer
    target_file = BytesIO()

    # Render template and save to the buffer
    template.render(context)
    template.save(target_file)

    # Reset the buffer's file-pointer to the beginning of the file
    target_file.seek(0)
 
    # return target file instead of send_file directly
    return target_file
```

My flask route that receives the axios call that receives the context attributes from Vue. The part with the file encoding is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57346338/how-to-return-image-stream-and-text-as-json-response-from-python-flask-api).

```
@hagis_api_bp.route('/docx/multiple', methods=['POST'])
def generate_word_multiple():
    request_json  = request.get_json()

    # array to store blob derivations
    blob_array = []

    for item in request_json['body']:
        context = json.loads(item)
        target_file = process.from_template_multiple(context)

        # encode as base64
        from base64 import encodebytes
        encoded_file = encodebytes(target_file.getvalue()).decode('ascii')

        # append target file to blob array
        blob_array.append(encoded_file)

    return jsonify({'result': blob_array})
```

And finally the Vue part. This axios call is used to send the context information (json) and here I want to return the blob_array and then revert the encoding process to receive the "raw" blob files.

```
    // axios request + file download
    axios({
      url: 'docx/multiple',
      data: {body: body_array},
      method: 'POST',

    }).then((response) => {
        // looping over each element in response.data (each converted bytesIO string)
        response.data['result'].forEach((element) => {
        
        // convert string to blob here ?
        
        // download blob as docx file
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([converted_element])); // --> using result from missing conversion above
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'title.docx');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The following axios request does the trick.
This question was very helpful: [Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

```
// axios request + file download
        axios({
          url: 'docx/multiple',
          data: {body: body_array},
          method: 'POST',

        }).then((response) => {
          response.data['result'].forEach((element) => {
            console.log(element)

            // decode string to blob --> solution to question
            const byteCharacters = atob(element);
            const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
              byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            console.log(byteArray)

            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'test.docx');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
          });
});
```